# Issues with recursive calls while building a Tree datastructure

Tags: python-2.7, tree, tail-recursion

I've been trying to figure out how to recursively call a function in python for the last few days to no avail.  I'm building a tree structure to store objects and have issues with not only traversing the tree using a generator, but also with making recursive calls to my find function.

Here is my code.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data, children=list()):
        self.data = data
        self.children = children

    def __eq__(self, node):
        return self.data == node.data

    def __str__(self):
        return self.data

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.data

    def write_xtl(self, node, out_file, level=0):
        gen2 = self.traverse(node)
        for child in gen2:
            out_file.write(child.data)

    def traverse(self, node, path=list()):
        yield self
        for n in self.children:
            for m in traverse(n, path):
                yield m

    def find(self, node):
        if self == node:
            return self
        else:
            for child in self.children:
                return child.find(node)

    def add(self, node, value):
        entry_point = self.find(node)
        if entry_point:
            #print ("Found %s in %s") % (value.data.rstrip(), node.data.rstrip())
            #print ("\tentry_point is %s") % (entry_point.data)
            entry_point.children.append(value)
        else:
            print ("Could not find %s") % (value)
```

---

Here's my test file:

```
from xtensiltree import tree
root = tree.Node("root\n")
header = tree.Node("header\n")
orderHeader = tree.Node("orderHeader\n")
date = tree.Node("date\n")
notes = tree.Node("notes\n")
address = tree.Node("address\n")
contacts = tree.Node("contacts\n")

root.add(root, header)
root.add(header, orderHeader)
root.add(orderHeader, date)
root.add(orderHeader, notes)
root.add(orderHeader, address)
root.add(address, contacts)

outfile = open("ooutput.xtl", "w")
root.write_xtl(root, outfile)
outfile.close()
```

---

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some example how find method should look like.

```
def find(self, node):
    if self == node:
        return self
    elif self.children != []:
        for child in self.children:
            found = child.find(node)
            if found:
                return found
    return None
```

Basicly, it means: if the current node is what we are looking for then return it. If not and the current node has children search them. If it's been found in one of children it will be returned, otherwise return None.

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't work with my code either.  I've tried various iterations of my find method, and I've tried raising the recursion limit.  No clue why the maximum recursion depth is reached all the time.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was with my **init**() method.

> def **init**(self, data, children=list()):

The list in my tree was declared global.  This caused every element of my tree to have the same children.

In turn, any recursive functions would go on forever.

Thanks for the help Tiero.